# Why does my website crash in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, crash

My site works fine in Firefox, but it crashes in IE.

I am using alot of jQuery in order to fade in content. When the user clicks on one of the above links a few times, it will crash in IE.

Here is my site: [Idea Palette](http://www.idea-palette.com/)

I have absolutely no idea why the site crashes in IE. I don't even know where to begin to debug my problem. I don't have Visual Studio on my computer, but on my friends computer Visual Studio reads a message of "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in iexplore.exe[####]"

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I haven't seen anything yet.  but I would definately recommend that you clean up your whitespace, by getting rid of your extra tabs.  I would also consider consolidating any code that is duplicated repeatedly, but thats a different question.

Comment: If you can crash IE from your website, you should report the problem to Microsoft. Any bug that can allow an attacker to crash a program on a victim's machine from a remote server is a potential security exploit (and it at least allows a denial of service).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go.  It has something to do with your DirectX filter (probably what's doing the fades).  Here's the stack, and EAX is NULL.  Whatever the code is doing is trying to deref EAX:

```
CDXTFilterBehavior::_ClearSurface:
6C8E87E1  mov         edi,edi 
6C8E87E3  push        ebp  
6C8E87E4  mov         ebp,esp 
6C8E87E6  push        ecx  
6C8E87E7  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] 
6C8E87EA  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax] <--- EAX is NULL

>   dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_ClearSurface()     
    dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_DrawUnfilteredElementLayers()  
    dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_DrawElementWithProceduralSurfaces()    
    dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_ExecuteFilterChain()   
    dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::Draw()  
    mshtml.dll!CPeerHolder::Draw()  
    mshtml.dll!CLayout::DrawClientLayers()  
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()    
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()    
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()    
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()    
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()    
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()   
    mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()    
    mshtml.dll!CDispRoot::DrawEntire()  
    mshtml.dll!CDispRoot::DrawRoot()    
    mshtml.dll!CView::RenderView()  
    mshtml.dll!CDoc::OnPaint()  
    mshtml.dll!CServer::OnWindowMessage()   
    mshtml.dll!CDoc::OnWindowMessage()  
    mshtml.dll!CServer::WndProc()   
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24()     
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()    
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    
    user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@20()  
    user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    
    user32.dll!_NtUserDispatchMessage@4()   
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()   
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()    
    ieframe.dll!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc()  
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()     
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

Perhaps you're removing an element from the DOM while the transform is still operating on it?

Comment: Where did you get the above code? How can I go about fixing the EAX? I have no idea what an EAX is, btw.

Comment: I ran iexplore.exe with Visual Studio attached and loaded public symbols.  EAX is a CPU register.  You can't fix it directly... you have to figure out how to work around it.  The fact that it's null is your only clue--whatever object you thought you were acting on is not there.

Comment: I used the Divide and Conquer approach, and as soon as I commented out the first section of javascript that controls the slideshow, it started working fine. Therefore, the fading of the pages in combination with the fading of the slideshow makes Internet Explorer crash. I have no idea why though.

Comment: BTW, the fact that it is NULL means the crash is not exploitable. If the address dereferenced is non-NULL (at least 0x1000), the crash should be sent to MSRC at secure@microsoft.com instead of being posted here.

Answer (score 10):

I can suggest that you have to follow the "Divide and Conquer Strategy".

Remove all your javascript, and try to load it, if it fail the problem is with the code you have removed. Now add again "half" of the code that you have removed, if it didn't crash then the problems isn't in this half, if it crashes again then it is in the half you have added. Now you have to keep adding "half" of the remaining code when it works, or removing half of the code you have added if it fails. If you keep doing this eventually you will led to a piece of code that you can't divide and if added make IE crash.

This will not solve your bug but it may give you an idea where the real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XP specific issue. We have a full team of developers looking into the issue so you will not see the same issue in Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Going on from what @jeffamaphone was saying, if it is something to do with modifying the DOM then it might be worth moving your JavaScript from the <head> to just before the closing </body> tag.

I have had issues with IE before and the [infamous Operation Aborted error](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ie6+operation+aborted) and doing this helped fix that, but I appreciate that YMMV.