# Why does my site crash in IE7 when fading to a page that has another fade on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, crash

Please look at **http://www.idea-palette.com**

I have multiple pages that are being faded in using the top nav. When the user clicks on any of the above buttons to fade in another page that contains the Slideshow using the jQuery Cycle Plugin, IE7 crashes.

When I comment out the jQuery that controls the fades of the slideshow, IE7 does not crash anymore.
You can see that here: **http://www.idea-palette.com/IEindex.php**

I'm guessing IE7 does not like it when it fades to some content that contains some other content that is in the process of fading already. I'm guessing the two together somehow overload IE7 so it crashes.

Before I figured out that the jQuery Cycle Plugin was causing the page to crash, I asked why this was happening([Why does my website crash in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723823/why-does-my-website-crash-in-ie)) and jeffamaphone on stackoverflow found out this info when looking at my site:

'It has something to do with your DirectX filter (probably what's doing the fades). Here's the stack, and EAX is NULL. Whatever the code is doing is trying to deref EAX:

> CDXTFilterBehavior::_ClearSurface:
>   6C8E87E1  mov         edi,edi
>   6C8E87E3  push        ebp
>   6C8E87E4  mov         ebp,esp
>   6C8E87E6  push        ecx
>   6C8E87E7  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
>   6C8E87EA  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax] <--- EAX is NULL
>
> dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_ClearSurface()
>       dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_DrawUnfilteredElementLayers()
>       dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_DrawElementWithProceduralSurfaces()
>       dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::_ExecuteFilterChain()
>       dxtrans.dll!CDXTFilterBehavior::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CPeerHolder::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CLayout::DrawClientLayers()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawChildren()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispContainer::DrawSelf()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispNode::Draw()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispRoot::DrawEntire()
>       mshtml.dll!CDispRoot::DrawRoot()
>       mshtml.dll!CView::RenderView()
>       mshtml.dll!CDoc::OnPaint()
>       mshtml.dll!CServer::OnWindowMessage()
>       mshtml.dll!CDoc::OnWindowMessage()
>       mshtml.dll!CServer::WndProc()
>       user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()
>       user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()
>       user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24()
>       user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()
>       user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()
>       user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()
>       user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@20()
>       user32.dll!_fnDWORD@4()
>       ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()
>       user32.dll!_NtUserDispatchMessage@4()
>       user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()
>       user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()
>       ieframe.dll!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc()
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
>       ntdll.dll!_RtlUserThreadStart@8()
>       ntdll.dll!_RtlUserThreadStart@8()

Perhaps you're removing an element from the DOM while the transform is still operating on it?'

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment the last time you posted this, if you can crash IE remotely, you should [contact Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/contactbug/). This vulnerability can lead at least to a denial of service attack, and potentially a remote code execution or remote root (a bug that lets a web page crash a browser on demand has a high likelyhood of being exploitable to allow the attacker to run untrusted code on your machine). While people here may be able to help you work around your problem, Microsoft really ought to be informed so they can fix the underlying bug.

**edit**: Both for trying to work around your own problem, and for the sake of reporting the bug, you should try and reduce the problem to a minimal test case. Strip all of the content down to a minimal set of elements that is sufficient for reproducing the bug. Then do the same with the code. You should endeavor to get a test case that is just one or two images, and just the crossfades that trigger the problem, with nothing else present.

Then, yes, to report the bug, send them a link to your minimal test case (or include it inline in the bug report if you can). Mention that it is a remote denial of service vulnerability, and that you don't know if it could lead to remote code execution.

And as I mentioned, cutting this down to a minimal example should be able to help you workaround your bug. At the very least, you're more likely to get help here on a minimal code example than an entire site with lots of stuff going on that no one really feels like digging through.

Comment: so i should give microsoft the web address and tell them that 'This vulnerability can lead at least to a denial of service attack, and potentially a remote code execution or remote root'?

Comment: @Chris Answered your questions in the answer, since I didn't have the room in the comment box. I don't have any idea how you can work around the problem; I would suggest cutting it down to a minimal example and posting again to see if anyone can help you.