# IE7 Crashing on some machines, errors in Debug bar, but don't see 'showstopper'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've recently been made aware that my site is crashing in IE7. I tested it on a bunch of machines myself, but of course it always runs perfectly. 
My brother just showed me IE7 on his computer, and it definitely crashes.

I've got 'debugbar' running, and it shows some errors in the HTMLCheck, and is warning that fb:login-button is not recognized (but of course it is allowed).

I run javascript check and it says

```
Script Error:
//----------------
Line: 1
Character: 6
Code: 0
Error Message: Syntax error
```

I can't actually see any script error myself.

The link is http://HearWhere.com

If somebody could help me figure out why this is failing on 15% or so of IE users, I'd be very very greatful. 
Pete

Comment: News flash: Using Flash on your web site is a BAD idea.

Comment: Also, you have so many external dependencies that you are just asking for inconsistent and uncontrollable problems.

Comment: Crashes for me on a virtual machine without Flash loaded. I hate annoying Flash embeds as much as the next guy, but “using it is BAD” might be overegging it slightly...

Comment: Could it be the same fade-related crash bug noted here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723823/why-does-my-website-crash-in-ie

Comment: The flash embed doesn't hit until the user clicks, so it isn't the flash that is killing the page. And Josh, if Flash was so 'BAD', it wouldn't be used on major sites like ummmmm YouTube, MySpace, etc. etc. 

As for external dependencies, I don't believe their is any other way to include FB Connect, Google Maps API, etc, etc, and I suspect the chances that those always fail on one IE7 machine and not others would be very slim. I can't get it to fail on my machine, it only fails on some others.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely does crash IE7 on a virtual machine I have. It's worth doing a bit of an audit for a start - for example, you're including and calling the Google Analytics JS twice, which is probably screwing up your stats if nothing else.

I've had crashes related to jQuery in IE7 before, all of which I could put down to large jQuery loops. Have a look through your code and comment parts where you are looping over the results of a jQuery select that could have a large number of results, or times when you are inserting a large number of elements into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Javascript errors (according to FireBug), but a large number of errors in the CSS for that page, any one of which could be antagonising IE7.

Comment: Thanks Julian, by CSS errors I assume you mean DOM/HTML errors? I didn't realize that CSS errors could kill a browser. The error is inconsistent on IE7 (not on my machine, yes on my brothers), so I'm still fairly lost.

Comment: No, there's typos in the CSS you're using, e.g. 'margin-botton', 'pading-right'. I'd be surprised if CSS on its own would actually crash any browser, as bad CSS is usually silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a really nice javascript debugger, but it doesn't crash in IE8 for me. Previously I used Microsoft Script Editor for debuggin in IE 6 & 7. For some strange reason it's bundled with Microsoft Office! It's a bit hassle to setup, but it works.

http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html

Answer (score -1):

If you are crashing, the JS code is not a likely cause. You need to look at isolating the specific OS, IE version number, patch level, and external dependencies (versions of flash, etc).