# jQuery Events in IE6 stop working or crashes IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have this sample fiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/sPDSZ/

This page has four event managers: two of which are actually two events captured each.

Two handle mouse events on the delete button highlight/remove highlight on the delete button ancestor.

Click on the delete button removes that ancestor that is highlighted.

Click on the Add button adds a copy of the first group using jQuery clone, with events, data and content all cloned.

In IE8 it works fine, even in compatibilty mode.

In IE6 however, adding, deleting and mouse over events stop happening with several groups added, then remove some, then add more etc. (using care not to remove root group)  Not all elements lose the events, but continued use eventually will degrade to nothing working except the Add event.

**Any idea how to work around what appears to be a bug in a jQuery IE6 combination?**

Note: in the original page I extracted this simplistic example from, it crashes browser on the page in some instances.

Background: originally had .delegate and that crashed every time, changed to "on()" and it only crashes part of the time now.

The client requires use of IE6 so I have no choice in that. :(

EDIT: Is there something in the event management that differs in IE6 that might impact here where I could do something different to avoid?

Comment: Wild guess: try `.closest('.wrapperRow')` to find your target containers instead of chained `.parent()` calls. I remember having problems with IE6 DOM traversal and text nodes...

Comment: I tried your suggestion of .closest http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/sPDSZ/9/ and also parentsUntil http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/sPDSZ/8/ but both these also have event management stop working on IE6 after repeated add/delete on multiple groups.

Comment: I would also try `.clone(false)` when you clone the template row. It looks like you don't need to clone the event handlers, since they're delegated to `#wrapperRows`. That *may* help IE6...

Comment: I changed to clone(false,true) and it still stops the events. Sometimes partially (as before some groups) until finally everywhere, usually with the .addClass (still on some element).

Comment: If you use `true` for the second argument, events will still be cloned. See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: I am facing the same problem, Have u been able to come up with a workaround?

Comment: @Brutallus - no resolution at this point

Answer (score 0):

I found a very similar issue on IE7. In my case, the browser folded on attempts to use JQuery selectors on elements that weren't yet available to the DOM (a timing issue), so perhaps check to see when you're using .clone(), and if the item you're cloning exists (at the time you're trying to clone it).

It appears to have something to do with the way the old IE browsers handle DOM manipulation at the root of the application.

A comprehensive explanation can be found as an answer to the following question.

[Why does my website crash in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723823/why-does-my-website-crash-in-ie)